# IP address v/s machine name

Tags: c#, java, sharepoint, networking

My server name : server, my server ip is 192.168.10.200

`SPSite site = new SPSite("192.168.10.200:7000")`  throws the following exception:

> The Web application at
>   http://192.168.10.200:7000 could not
>   be found. Verify that you have typed
>   the URL correctly. If the URL should
>   be serving existing content, the
>   system administrator may need to add a
>   new request URL mapping to the
>   intended application

.

while
`SPSite site = new SPSite("server:7000")` works perfectly.

any ideas?

OS: Windows 7 64 bits + Sharepoint 2010

Comment: Please fix your question: does `server` map to `192.168.10.200` or to `192.168.30.170`? Do you use port `7000` or `8000`?

Answer (score 3):

Your server is set up for serving more than one website and uses a Host header in the http request to sort out which one a request is for.

If you give it the IP address, it doesn't know which web server is meant.

Answer (score 1):

The site could be configured with a [host header](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28WS.10%29.aspx) for `server` and thus only answering on that and not on IP.

Answer (score 0):

One clue is that your code says the port number is 7000 but the error message says it is 8000.  Is that a typo in your actual code, or did you make a mistake in transcribing the code or message into your Question?

Also, the IP addresses don't match.